# What is the most easy way (similar to pandas) to run RandomForest or GBT classifier on pyspark?

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark

Suppose I have a CSV files with some non-related columns (ID, names etc.), some feature columns with all kinds of different (the list of features is stored in a Python list) and a target column (`y`).

In `pandas` it is quite easy to have something like:

`clf.fit (X= df[features], y = df[target])`

But I have trouble to figure out how to do something similar with pyspark, given that I read the CSV file into a PySpark dataframe already.

Any help is appreciate.

Many thanks.

Comment: I’m not sure I understand what reading the CSV into a PySpark DataFrame has to do with the rest of the question. In any case, have you read the PySpark docs, for example?

Comment: Yes, for instance reading this one https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-classification-regression.html#random-forest-classifier but I am still confused.

Comment: As far as I can tell, no one on Stack Overflow can read minds. You’re going to need to be **far more** specific and detailed.

Comment: I suppose the doc you mentioned gives sufficient explanation.. If you are confused with **pipeline**, its there in [sklearn too](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html).. first read it.. it will clear your confusion